# How to save a date in MySQL database with specific format?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have insert query with the following information I want to put in MySQL database the problem that I have is with date value :

```
INSERT INTO odds (match_id, market_id, bookmaker_id, 3way_result_1, 3way_result_x, 3way_result_2, match_date) 
VALUES (1682572, 1, 21, 3.15, 1.00, 1.00, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('18.02.2014','%d.%m.%Y'), '%d.%m.%Y'))
```

str_to_date alone work fine (saved right date but with YYYY-mm-dd) but when i add DATE_FORMAT it saved as wrong value "2018-02-20"

I want to save it in the format of '18.02.2014'

can u correct my query?

Comment: Instead save like YYYY-mm-dd then while select use date format to convert back dd-mm-YYYY

Comment: Why do people get silly ideas constantly.. just save the date like MySQL wants it and format it **when you pull it out**. If you save the date like you want to, you lose all the nice features with dates that MySQL offers you.

Answer (score 3):

From [this manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) MySql date data type only allows you to use format YYYY-mm-dd to store. But while selecting data, you can use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format your result as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Column match_date is a date column hopefully. So STR_TO_DATE already produces the needed date from the date string. Just remove the DATE_FORMAT part from your INSERT statement.